# C# how to call this code correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, api

I'm trying to integrate this TwitchTv API XML code to my own project, but i can't get it to work when i try to call `getStreamInfo` in for example `button1_Click event`.

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace jsontest //change this if you want
{
public class twitchTVAPIModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ChannelOwner { get; set; }
    public string ChannelUrl { get; set; }
    public int ViewerCount { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
}
public class twitch
{
    public List<twitchTVAPIModel> getStreamInfo(string channel)
    {
        string uriEndPoint = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel=" + channel;
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(uriEndPoint);
        var streams = (from stream in xmlDocument.Descendants("stream")
                       select new twitchTVAPIModel()
                       {
                           Title = stream.Element("title").Value,
                           ViewerCount = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Element("stream_count").Value),
                           Status = stream.Element("status").Value,
                           Username = stream.Element("channel").Element("login").Value,
                           ChannelUrl = stream.Element("channel").Element("channel_url").Value,
                           GameTitle = stream.Element("channel").Element("meta_game").Value
                       }).ToList<twitchTVAPIModel>();
        return streams;
    }
}
}
```

The line:

`public List<twitchTVAPIModel> getStreamInfo(string channel)`

is not clear to me and that's one reason why i don't understand how to call it correctly.

Comment: What is failing for you?

Comment: It declares a method, `getStreamInfo`, which accepts one parameter named `channel` of type `string`, and returns an object of type `List<twitchTVAPIModel>`. Is it the `<...>` that you're confused by?

Comment: well for starters.. it doesnt even recognize getStreamInfo outside of that code area, (for example in the button1 event)

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes, do i need that while calling it from button1_click? and if so then how exactly ?

Comment: Is `button1_Click` in the same namespace?

Comment: You will treat it like you would any other return type. `List<twitchTVAPIModel> myList = instance.getStreamInfo("foo")` or more simply `var myList = instance.getStreamInfo("foo")`

Comment: No offense intended, but I *think* you should try writing some *Hello World* stuff in C# first before trying to integrate 3rd party libraries and custom types. If you have previous experience in other languages, that may take as little as a day and then you're good to go.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper none taken, you are proably right* , the holidays are coming soon and then i will start learning it more seriously, but right now i would wanna get this to work

Comment: @p.s.w.g The error that i am getting is: "The name 'instance' does not exist in the current context", this occured when i tried to do it on my own too

Comment: @rip2444: Do *you* want to get it to work, or do you want *someone else* to get it to work? In the former case, how could that be possible if you do not know what you are doing? The error messages you are seeing are very descriptive and exactly describe the problem.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ok, i see ur point, nvm with this question then, will start learning it properly from the start in a few weeks when i have time. Just wanted to try something like this.

Comment: @rip2444 You need to call `getStreamInfo` on a valid instance of the type it's declared on. I can't open the pastebin link ATM (which is one reason you should include the relevant portion of code in the question), so I can't tell you more than that.

Comment: @rip2444: Feel free to ask in case of problems here that really block you, but please make sure that your questions are about *specific* problems, one at a time. It seems to me like you are trying to take 3 steps (invoking a method, taking the result of the method, accessing identifiers from a different scope, ...) at a time.

Comment: @p.s.w.g i edited the code if u want to see it, will start learning c# properly soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
public List<twitchTVAPIModel> getStreamInfo(string channel)
```

Is a method header stating that the function `getStreamInfo`accepts a `string` as it's only parameter and will return a `List` of `twitchTVAPIModel` objects

Edit: Since the function is not static, you will be required to instantiate an `Twitch` object before you can call this function

```
var twitch = new Twitch();
var results = twitch.getStreamInfo("someChannel");
```

Comment: OP wants to know how to call it, too. Please provide an example of that as well.